# Compute the hash of an empty array of 32 bytes

Tags: scala, hash

I've been asked to compute the hash of an empty array of 32 bytes.

Here is my solution :

```
val instance = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
val hash = instance.digest(Array.fill[Byte](32)(0))
```

This compiles without error but I'm unsure if I should use 0 in computing an `empty` array.

The term "empty array of 32 bytes" seems contradictory to me but I may not be understanding something.

Is my implementation correct?

Update:

On further inspection by default, the digest length is 32.

Using this code prints 32 :

```
println(MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").getDigestLength)
```

Comment: That is not really an empty array, that is an array of 32 elements, where each element is a byte of value zero. But I am also puzzled if that is considered empty or not in your context.

Comment: I think, if the ask doesn't make sense to you, it would make more sense to clarify it with whoever asked you do this then to expect that someone here will be able to guess correctly what they meant.